# Should we use "is sending" or "is to send"?

Tags: verb-forms, infinitives, gerunds

In the sentence below:

> The only way to communicate with me is **________** me directly an email.

should I fill in the blank with *sending* or *to send*?  Or will both work?

Is there a general rule to determine when should we use ***verb*-ing** or **to *verb***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think either form would be acceptable, but something else is bothering me about the sentence. I would move the word “directly” to the end of the sentence:

> The only way to communicate with me is to send me an email directly.
>
> The only way to communicate with me is sending me an email directly.

Of these cases, I would prefer to hear the first option. It sounds more natural to me.

---

You can make the second sound more natural by adding “by”:

> The only way to communicate with me is **by** sending me an email directly

Adding “by” has a lot of impact on how I read the sentence, and it suddenly feels very natural. Not sure why, though. I would say that when using this form, *always* use “by”.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you what to say. However in your case 'is to send' is fine. Therefore: "The only way to communicate with me is *to send me* directly an email." However you can simply say it as: "Email is the only way to communicate with me"